# No access to MessageBox class in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I'm creating a `Windows Runtime App` and it seems I don't have any access to the `MessageBox` class. The documentation states it's in the `System.Windows` namespace, so I added it and I still don't have access to the `MessageBox` class.

[image]

```
using System.Windows;
public sealed partial class BillPage : Page
{

    private Edge myEdge;
    public BillPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test");           
    }
}
```

Any idea what's up? Am I just an idiot or what?
Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.messagebox(v=vs.105).aspx

Full Code:

```
using EdgeApp.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Windows;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390556

namespace EdgeApp
{

    public sealed partial class BillPage : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
        private Edge myEdge;
        public BillPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            myEdge = new Edge();
            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

        }


        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }

        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }


        private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion

        private void MessageBoxTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("text");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "don't have access to MessageBox class"? Compile-time error or runtime error or it doesn't work or ...?

Comment: The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context. I'm going crazy right now. It's like the most basic thing ever.

Comment: Try adding "using System.Windows.Forms;"

Comment: Can't use the Forms messagebox in a Windows Store App. I tried manually referencing the DLL and it crashed when I tried to pop it up haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Runtime App, MessageBox can be shown by this code:

```
new MessageDialog("Your Message Content").ShowAsync();
```

Comment: My god you're a savior... If only they would update their documentation. Thank you a ton, Chris! Any idea why the other documentation shows that you can use the MessageBox class?

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe their document hasn't be updated totally.

Comment: Even googling only tells you to use the MessageBox.... https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How+to+show+message+on+Windows+Phone

Comment: Yes, MessageBox can be used in Windows Phone 8. But can't in Windows Phone 8.1(Runtime)